# How does connecting Namespaces work in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to print out a number from a different namespace in my main. I will provide the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world" + x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace Applicaton
{

    class Program2
    {
        public int Test()
        {
            int x = 5;
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have the x from Program2 class appear in my main which is in Program Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the class.

```
 Program2 p = new Program2();
 Console.WriteLine(p.Test().toString());
```

and what ever Program2 have you can call on it. 
or assign it.

```
int num = p.Test();
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

then print it.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your code like below. Since your `Program2` is defined in another class, by any means you will have to fully qualify it with namespace name while accessing it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world" + new Applicaton.Program2().Test());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First make Decalare Application as referenced namespace, then set program2 as public, set x as public properties for program2. then use class program2 in main.

Below is the source code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Applicaton;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program2 p= new Program2();
            Console.WriteLine("hello world" + p.x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace Applicaton
{

    public class Program2
    {
        public int x;
        public int Test()
        {
            x = 5;
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class and call the method on it.

```
Program2 program = new Program2();
int x = program.Test();
Console.WriteLine("hello world" + x);
```

Make sure you include the namespace:

```
using Application;
```

Comment: @user700390 OP is clearly trying to print that value, not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Programming does not behave like this. Namespaces asides, learn some Object Oriented principles.

What you will need is to 'new' or instantiate up a Program2 object that can call the Test() method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Application;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Program2 program = new Program2();
                //Below I am calling the Test() method knowing that Test() will return a value to save from having to initialize another variable.
                Console.WriteLine("hello world" + program.Test());
            }
        }
    }
    namespace Applicaton
    {

        class Program2
        {
            public int Test()
            {
                int x = 5;
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
```